# Ruby: Prepared statement with Like

Tags: ruby, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a prepared statement with the `like` keyword:

This is the sql statement:

```
select user, 
       name_xml 
  from employee
 where name_xml like '<name>Varname</name>'
```

`Varname` is a dynamic variable. It can consist of any string value. For eg: `Varname = 'John Smith'`

Code:

```
sql_name = @dbh.prepare(sql)

sql = 'select user, name_xml from employee
where name_xml  like '<name>?</name>''

sql_name.execute (Varname)
```

The issue I am facing is with "?" where it should contain Varname string value. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most drivers won't recognize a `?` as a placeholder when it is inside a string literal. To get around this, you have a couple options. First of all, you could do the string work in Ruby:

```
sql = 'select user, name_xml from employee where name_xml like ?'
#...
sql_name.execute("<name>#{Varname}</name>")
```

Or you could paste the pieces together in SQL:

```
sql = %q{select user, name_xml from employee where name_xml like '<name>' || ? || '</name>'}
#...
sql_name.execute(Varname)
```

The `||` should concatenate strings in most databases but some will want `+` or `concat(...)` instead.

Note the switch to `%q{...}` for quoting in the second one, that acts like a single quoted (Ruby) string but you don't have to worry about escaping the embedded single quotes that SQL wants to use for its string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response! That should work. I have tried the following and it also works perfectly:

```
sql = 'select user, name_xml from employee
where name_xml  like ('#{test}')'


Varname = "John Smith" 
  test = "%<name>"+Varname+"</name>%"

 sql_name= @dbh.prepare(sql)

  sql_name.execute()

  sql_name.fetch do |row|
    sql_name =  row[0]
  end
```